# redirect user back to previous page after authenticating user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can't seem to figure out how to return to previous page after authenticating the user.  I tried return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl) but that always takes the user back to the main home index page.  When I use return Redirect(returnUrl) it reloads the previous page.  However, the previous page has objects in the ViewBag that are null at that point.  I just want the user to return to the previous page retaining the State keeping all of the entered data on the shopping cart checkout page.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

How are you redirecting them to the Login page - manually or with attributes? Adding `[Authorize]` to your controller class is the easiest way and by default works as expected. e.g.

`[Authorize]
public class TestController : Controller`

For your situation you might want to place the Authorize attribute on an Action and not an entire controller

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ConfirmShoppingCart()
```

The benefit of this approach is further [customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)

A possible last resort is to manually place a condition on the view rendering your "Proceed" button (or whatever you want to trigger authentication).

E.g.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
//normal proceed'

} else {
     @Html.ActionLink("Proceed", "Login", "Account", new { @returnUrl = Url.Action("ViewCart", "ShoppingCart")}, new { } )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following ::

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(User model, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Lets first check if the Model is valid or not

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (DbEntities entities = new DbEntities())
                {
                    string username = model.UserID;
                    string password = model.Password;

                    var UserAuth = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == model.UserID && x.Password == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();

                    // Now if our password was enctypted or hashed we would have done the
                    // same operation on the user entered password here, But for now
                    // since the password is in plain text lets just authenticate directly

                    bool userValid = entities.Users.Any(user => user.UserID == username && user.Password == password);
                    var usr = entities.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == username && x.Password == password);
                    if (userValid)
                    {
                        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["_SessionCompany"] = usr.DefaultCompanyID;

                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                        {
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dossier");
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: When I use Redirect(returnUrl) it "reloads" the previous page and the all of the data the user entered is blank.  I want to do something like go back history as in javascript.  Is that possible?

Comment: check properly by using Breakpoints that what is 'returnUrl' value